# Keras: DataFrameIterator - how to get next batch (TypeError: 'float' object is not callable)

Tags: python, keras

I am using `flow_from_dataframe` to construct a DataFrameIterator:

```
datagen=ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(...)

print(train_generator)
>> <keras_preprocessing.image.DataFrameIterator object at 0x00000262F5D93F60>
```

Now I am trying to get a single batch from this generator. Usually using `next(train_generator)` works on `flow_from_directory` generators, however this approach

```
x,y = next(train_generator)
```

and

```
x,y = train_generator.next
```

results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-6be8f38d3987> in <module>
----> 1 next(train_generator)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py in __next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1524 
   1525     def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1526         return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
   1527 
   1528     def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py in next(self)
   2201         # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
   2202         # so it can be done in parallel
-> 2203         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
   2160             params = self.image_data_generator.get_random_transform(x.shape)
   2161             x = self.image_data_generator.apply_transform(x, params)
-> 2162             x = self.image_data_generator.standardize(x)
   2163             batch_x[i] = x
   2164         # optionally save augmented images to disk for debugging purposes

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py in standardize(self, x)
   1117         """
   1118         if self.preprocessing_function:
-> 1119             x = self.preprocessing_function(x)
   1120         if self.rescale:
   1121             x *= self.rescale

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

How can I access a single batch (i.e. next batch)?

EDIT:
As pointed out by **@today** in the comments, using next(train_generator) should work just fine. In my case I was using the `preprocess_input` parameter in the `ImageDataGenerator` whereas I should have used the `rescale` parameter. Now the issue is solved!

Comment: Could you please provide the full stack trace?

Comment: @today I added the entire error message

Comment: Could you please format it as code block and not block quote? Just copy the stack trace, paste it here and then select it and press "code sample" button in the toolbar.

Comment: @today sure thing :)

Comment: Thanks. It seems there is something wrong with the `preprocessing_function` argument you may have set when creating the `ImageDataGenerator`. Could you please provide the full code for that part as well?

Comment: oh my god you are correct! I mixed up the "preprocess_input" parameter with the "rescale" parameter! Now its working fine, thank you so much for the critical hint!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x,y = next(iter(train_generator))
```